# Why doesn't Entity Framework add a "where" to the SQL generated when SingleOrDefault is used?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, code-first, ef4-code-only

I'm using Entity Framework CTP 5 with "code only" (with SQL Server 2008). I have an entity returned from a DbContext that I then access a child collection from, and select one item from it. Here's my LINQ statement:

```
Question currentQuestion = currentTopic.Questions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsCurrent);
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
[Extent1].[IsCurrent] AS [IsCurrent], 
[Extent1].[Xml] AS [Xml], 
[Extent1].[TopicId] AS [TopicId]
FROM [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[SessionId] = 24
```

My "IsCurrent" restriction isn't referenced at all. IsCurrent is a bit field in my database.

Can anyone explain why this is? It's causing a huge performance hit.

Comment: not sure... x => x.IsCurrent == true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is by design in all EF implementations. Questions collection exposes `IEnumerable<Question>` not `IQueryable<Question>`. When you access Questions property lazy loading is triggered and all related questions are loaded. Then you call `SingleOrDefault` on loaded collection.

If you want just single question run this query instead:

```
var question = context.Questions
                 .SingleOrDefault(q => q.Session.Id == sessionId && q.IsCurrent);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think because the child collection (`currentTopic.Questions`) is lazily loaded *completely* and then the LINQ to Object version of SingleOrDefault and not the LINQ to Entities one is called on your collection.

The SQL statement you posted contains `WHERE [Extent1].[SessionId] = 24`. That shows it's loading all Questions for your currentTopic.